# Calculated Field Not Showing Value - Ms.Access

Tags: ms-access, textbox, calculated-field

I am creating a student report card in ms access and there are five texboxes which can either be fill totally or few of them can be left unfilled. I have applied a formula through expression builder to add all the values in those five fields and display the calculated result in that specifix textbox.
But the problem here is that the textbox is not showing the result untill all the values are filled. If any of those five boxes remain null, the calculated result wont show up.

Here is the formula

[mo1]+[mo2]+[mo3]+[mo4]+[mo5]
and being stored in [Totalmarks]

I have also tried using the update query but the result remain the same. kindly help in this regard. Thanks

Comment: IS YOUR  textbox format is Number.?

Comment: i am referring to sql connected database where the textbox is of type INT

Answer (score 1):

Null plus anything yields Null.

You can use [Nz Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) to substitute zero for Null when adding the textbox values.

```
Nz([mo1], 0) + Nz([mo2], 0) + Nz([mo3], 0) + Nz([mo4], 0) + Nz([mo5], 0)
```

Comment: going to give it a try

Comment: the nz function didnt work. the field is still showin no value at all

Answer (score -1):

dude you might be using a calculated field in the expression builder. take the values from the actual data cell, not a calculated one

for example
amt xx
tax xxx
total = amt + tax

advance = yy

then,

balance = amt + tax - adv   (this is correct)
balance = total - adv (this is wrong)

dont know the reason behind it, but it worked for me.